# Can FWER corrected p-values be called q-values?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate, familywise-error

This is a very naive question but I feel that many people in research do not have a very clear guidelines about what can or cannot be called a "q-value". I thought I had it right but I find so many people around me that think the opposite.

I do not think FWER corrected p-values can be called q-values. Q-values are only related to FDR. Am I right?